# HTML Form: Select-Option to insert data into MySQL phpmyadmin database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a php file named "add_report" with a form inside it. All my inputs are running, i can input data into my database, but everytime I use the select-option. my database accepts it as null. Why is that?

This is my form "add_report.php"

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <form action="add_report_backend.php" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="id">
      <label>Agency: </label> <input class="input1" type="text" name="agency" value="CAAP" required readonly><br>
      <label>File Name: </label> <input class="input2" type="text" name="filename" placeholder="file.pdf/xlsx/xls/docx" required autofocus><br>
      <label>File Type:  &nbsp;</label> <select name="myselectbox">
        <option name="myoption1" value="myoption1">pdf</option>
        <option name="myoption2" value="myoption2">excel</option>
        <option name="myoption3" value="myoption3">word</option>
      </select><br>
      <label>Date: </label> <input class="input4" type="Date" name="date" required><br>
  <input class="submit-btn" type="submit" name="insert" value="Save">
</form>
</div>
```

And this another php file "add_report_backend.php"

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['insert']))
{
    try {
    $pdoConnect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=annualdb","root","");

    $pdoConnect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch (PDOException $exc) {
        echo $exc->getMessage();
        exit();
    }
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $Agency = $_POST['agency'];
    $FName = $_POST['filename'];
    $FType = $_POST['filetype'];
    $Date = $_POST['date'];

    $pdoQuery = "INSERT INTO `company_report`(`agency`, `filename`, `filetype`, `date`) VALUES (:Agency,:FName,:FType,:Date)";
    $pdoResult = $pdoConnect->prepare($pdoQuery);
    $pdoExec = $pdoResult->execute(array(":Agency"=>$Agency,":FName"=>$FName,":FType"=>$FType, ":Date"=>$Date));

    if($pdoExec)
    {

        $pdoQuery = 'SELECT * FROM company_report';
        $pdoResult =  $pdoConnect->prepare($pdoQuery);
        $pdoResult->execute();
            while ($row = $pdoResult->fetch()){
                echo  $row['id'] . " | " .$row['agency'] . " | " . $row['filename'] . " | " . $row['filetype'] . " | " . $row['date'];
            }
            header("Location: ../agencies/company.php");
            exit;
        } else {
            echo 'Data Not Inserted';
    }
}
$pdoConnect = null;
?>
```

Comment: Have you checked if posted datas are not null before it saves to your database?

Comment: The data in my table are  NULL as default, should I change them as not null?

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Have you checked whether the proper data is transmitted to the server, whether it reaches the server, whether the proper variables where filled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML `name` attribute and the `$_POST` name should be the same.

You need to change

```
$FType = $_POST['filetype'];
```

by

```
$FType = $_POST['myselectbox'];
```

Comment: Thanks Pupil! It worked
 I also changed the value of my options to value="pdf", "excel" and "word" too.

Answer (score 2):

Change `$FType = $_POST['filetype'];` to `$FType = $_POST['myselectbox'];`